# What are three ways French cheese or "fromages" are categorized?

Tags: alimentation, culture

On my French study guide, there is a question asking what are three ways French cheese are categorized. However, when searching online, it said that there are 8 different ways they can be categorized. So, what are three **main** ways that they can be categorized? (the answers can be in English).

Comment: Note that this is barely on-topic here, as this question has rather little to do with language.

Comment: But it still has to do with French culture and alimentation which is a tag on this forum.

Comment: There's also a tag [tag:informatique], and still you can't ask computer questions here. It has to be related to language to be on-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three ways is not enough, unless maybe from the milk origin: *vache*, *chèvre*, or *brebis*.

[Wikipedia lists 10 groups](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_de_p%C3%A2tes_de_fromage) (one of which being Italian).

Answer (score 3):

Quleques façons de classer les fromages sont par exemple:

- le lait utilisé: vache, chèvre, brebis; lait cru ou pasteurisé
- la texture générale: pâte dure, pâte molle, pâte persillée; pâte crue ou pâte cuite
- la provenance géographique
- la durée d’affinage: fromage frais ou affiné
- la technique de fabrication: pâte pressée, filée, fondue

En général, quand on commande un plateau de fromages chez le crémier, on s’intéresse d’abord au type de lait et au type de pâte, parfois la provenance pour faire découvrir une région à un invité ou pour rendre hommage à la sienne.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say "A pâte molle", "A pâte dure" et "les bleus" but I'm not an expert.

Comment: It seems like a possible answer. Based on your reply, I found a section in the textbook that seems to explain it. It says this sentence: "Ils sont aussi classés selon leur fabrication: les fromages à pâte molle, à pate cuite, ou non cuite, à pâte persillee et les fromages frais." But it also says other things of groups (see the image attached). Here is the image of the [section](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzgoxy507it6h0w/Screen%20Shot%202017-12-03%20at%2012.14.59%20PM.png?dl=0)

Comment: persillés would be the same as bleus (they have that dodgy looking blue mold inside them)

Comment: Persillé couvre plus que les bleus: le roquefort est vert.

Comment: ok je m'avoue vaincu par le clacos françois ;)